# reading a barcode generated from a weight scale in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, scale, barcode, price

guys usually a scale's barcode contain digits that refer for the item itself and other digits which refers to the weight and price, all in the barcode itself. How can i read this barcode (getting the item in a textbox, the weight in other textbox and the price too)in vb.net.

any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most barcode reading components are able to read multiple barcodes per so all you have to do is to

- scan barcodes from image or web-cam
- check every barcode's value length or format to determine if a value relates to the price or weight
- additionally check `X` and `Y` coordinates of barcodes. If price barcode is always on top then you just need to find which barcode is placed higher by checking `barcode1.Y > barcode2.Y`

If you are looking for an open source barcode reading component then check [ZXing.NET](https://zxingnet.codeplex.com) project. If you are looking for commercially supported API then check [Leadtools](http://LEADTOOLS.com/sdk/barcode), [ByteScout BarCode Reader SDK](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/barcodereadersdk/bytescoutbarcodereadersdk.html) and [others](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=read%20barcode)

*Disclosure: I'm related with ByteScout*

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it will be a single barcode but with different parts of the data string holding different digits (each sub-string holds a value). For example, the first digit might indicate whether this is a combined barcode with weight and/or price in it. Digits 3 to 6 could hold the item code and digits 9 to 13 could hold the price or weight value.
To get the exact specs, you'll need the information from the manufacturer of the scale that prints the barcodes. To decode them, simply read the barcode (for example like Eugene M suggested) and get the string, then split it according to the scale manufacturer's specifications.